# Codeception Laravel sendAjaxGetRequest return empty string

Tags: laravel-4, codeception

Do you know why this return an empty string

```
public function tryToTest3(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('To see a 200 status code and a json response');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        $I->sendAjaxGetRequest('/users',array());

        $I->seeResponseCodeIs('200');
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();// until here green bar
        dd($I->grabResponse()); // empty string
    }

Acceptance Tests (5) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules: PhpBrowser, AcceptanceHelper, Db, REST
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to try to test (LoginCest::tryToTest)                                                                                                
Scenario:
 PASSED 

Trying to try to test2 (LoginCest::tryToTest2)                                                                                              
Scenario:
 PASSED 

Trying to To see a 200 status code and a json response (LoginCest::tryToTest3)                                                              
Scenario:
* I have http header "Content-Type","application/json"
* I send ajax get request "/users",
  [Response] 200
  [Page] http://localhost/laravel/phpunit/public/users
  [Cookies] []
  [Headers] {"Date":["Thu, 31 Jul 2014 08:49:58 GMT"],"Server":["Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)"],"X-Powered-By":["PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4"],"Vary":["Accept-Encoding"],"Content-Length":["120"],"Content-Type":["text/html"]}
* I see response code is "200"
* I see response is json 
* I grab response 
string(0) ""
```

**NB**

in my app/bootstrap/start.php I've got

```
if ((gethostname() === 'homestead') && (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) && ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1'))
{
    dd('homestead');
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(['codeception' => ['homestead']]);
}
else
{ 
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(['local' => ['homestead']]);
}
```

*homestead* is never printed

while this print the actual response and print *homestead*

```
public function tryToTest3(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('To see a 200 status code and a json response');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        $I->sendGET('/users',array());

        $I->seeResponseCodeIs('200');
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();
        dd($I->grabResponse()); // the good response
    }
    Scenario:
     PASSED 

    Trying to To see a 200 status code and a json response (LoginCest::tryToTest3)                                                              
    Scenario:
    * I have http header "Content-Type","application/json"
    * I send get "/users",
      [Request] GET http://localhost/laravel/phpunit/public//users
      [Response] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
      [Headers] {"Date":["Thu, 31 Jul 2014 09:12:43 GMT"],"Server":["Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)"],"X-Powered-By":["PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4"],"Cache-Control":["no-cache"],"Set-Cookie":["laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjdxSVE3RzFEYUw4Q0VmbWNWTzlVVkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSXY5c2xZbVlmdTdSU1hjNTJuVU1cLzlkZXRwQmRGOEc2R3dscTBtY3JHRVwvR3V5TWM2K1BkVkpmdERDY3h0NkloU09CaUFNN0cwSk56TDBZbmhIOVVLZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNzE2YTlhZGEyMTIyZTdlODQ0ZjA0ZGEzZjE5NDg0MTBlMWNkY2IzMzRkN2NhNjEzOTg5ZTQ5NmRkNDU2OTE4MyJ9; expires=Thu, 31-Jul-2014 11:12:43 GMT; path=/; httponly"],"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"Content-Type":["application/json"]}
      [Status] 200
    * I see response code is "200"
    * I see response is json 
    * I grab response 
    string(52) "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this instead of $I->grabResponse()

```
$response = $I->grabDataFromJsonResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but i think that in my case i have mistunderstood the testing tools.

> In my case i was trying to test a JSON response provided by a controller that accepted AJAX POST requests.
>
> I was trying to test that a successfull-style flash message is displayed to the user in a div, but as i wasn't able to test Javascript, i was looking for the JSON in the response. And then i reached your case when null is given as a JSON.

I tried with all the possible headers and combinations and then i reached this response in PHPtest.club and i think that it maybe can help you as it helped me.

It's about the difference between `sendPOST` and `sendAjaxPostRequest`, and then i realised that i was using in a wrong way the sendAjaxPostRequest.

http://phptest.club/t/what-is-the-difference-between-sendpost-and-sendajaxpostrequest/212

Basically:

- `sendAjaxXRequest` is used to test an `HTML response`, so you should use, `see`, `seeElement` and those methods.
- `sendX` is designed to work with `JSON response` and not with HTML, so you should use `seeResponeIsJSON` or all the other methods.

I hope to be helpful to you or someone else.

Greetings!

**I'd like to say thanks to davert for such a meaningful response.**

Comment: thank you for that very helpful & obscurely mentioned note.